# In Typescript how do you make a distinction between Node and vanilla Javascript Error types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following function:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a component template from filesystem
 */
const getComponentTemplate = async (
  p: string
): Promise<string> => {
  let template: string
  try {
    template = await fs.readFile(p, {
      encoding: 'utf8'
    })
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error && e.code === 'ENOENT') {
      throw new Error(`template for element type ${elementType} not found`)
    }
    throw e
  }

  return template
}
```

Typescript complains here:

`[ts] Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'`

This is because the Javascript `Error` class only has properties [message and name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

However, Node's `Error` class does have a [code property](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errorcode).

Typescript defines this in a special interface `ErrnoException` (see source [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2a1850482040d351929454fef723eedb49a75681/types/node/globals.d.ts#L193-L198)). I have added `@types/node` to my package.json, but this didn't make Typescript realize that this `Error` is part of the `ErrnoException` interface.

It is not possible to declare a type annotation in a catch clause. So, how does one make the Typescript compiler able to resolve that this is a Node Error?

FYI, this is part of my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017"]
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `e instanceof Error` you're testing to see if it's an `Error` not an `ErrnoException`. I'm not sure on the best way to tell it the right type, but a "quick n dirty" way is `e instanceof Error && (e as ErrnoException).code === 'ENOENT'`.

Comment: You can probably make a typeguard along the lines of this: `function isError(error: any): error is ErrnoException { return error instanceof Error; }` though it'd surprise me if something like that doesn't already exist. You'd this this would be a common requirement!

Comment: I realize that I could use `as` but this seems somewhat dirty. Shouldn't Typescript know that I am running in Node?

Comment: Wouldn't `if (e instanceof ErrnoException)` just fit your needs?

Comment: @arvymetal no because the class is actually `Error` (the one provided by Node). `ErrnoException` is only an interface, not a class. Therefore e is not an instance of it. Note that Node's `Error` implements `ErrnoException`, but for some reason Typescript doesn't realize this.

Comment: Ah I see! So AndyJS answer is the right way to create the typeguard

Answer (score 8):

### Type-safe TypeScript solution

It is not the universal solution, but works for the `ErrnoException` case.
According **"@types/node": "16.11.xx"** definitins, the `ErrnoException` is the interface:

```
interface ErrnoException extends Error {
   errno?: number | undefined;
   code?: string | undefined;
   path?: string | undefined;
   syscall?: string | undefined;
}
```

Below type guard fully respects this defenition. My TypeScript and ESLint settings are pretty strict, so with a high probability you will not need the comments disabling the ESLint/TSLint (if you still use this depricated one).

```js
function isErrnoException(error: unknown): error is ErrnoException {
  return isArbitraryObject(error) &&
    error instanceof Error &&
    (typeof error.errno === "number" || typeof error.errno === "undefined") &&
    (typeof error.code === "string" || typeof error.code === "undefined") &&
    (typeof error.path === "string" || typeof error.path === "undefined") &&
    (typeof error.syscall === "string" || typeof error.syscall === "undefined");
}
```

where

```js
type ArbitraryObject = { [key: string]: unknown; };

function isArbitraryObject(potentialObject: unknown): potentialObject is ArbitraryObject {
  return typeof potentialObject === "object" && potentialObject !== null;
}
```

Now we can check the `code` property:

```
import FileSystem from "fs";
import PromisfiedFileSystem from "fs/promises";

// ...

let targetFileStatistics: FileSystem.Stats;

try {

  targetFileStatistics = await PromisfiedFileSystem.stat(validAbsolutePathToPublicFile);

} catch (error: unknown) {

  if (isErrnoException(error) && error.code === "ENOENT") {

     response.
         writeHead(HTTP_StatusCodes.notFound, "File not found.").
         end();

     return;
  }

 
  response.
      writeHead(HTTP_StatusCodes.internalServerError, "Error occurred.").
      end();
}
```

I added **isErrnoException** type guard to my library [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-nodejs) but because I know that the promotion of third-party solutions could be annoying, I have posted the full implementation with usage example above =)

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using @AndyJ's comment:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a component template from filesystem
 */
const getComponentTemplate = async (
  p: string
): Promise<string> => {
  let template: string
  try {
    template = await fs.readFile(p, {
      encoding: 'utf8'
    })
  } catch (e) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unsafe-any
    if (isNodeError(e) && e.code === 'ENOENT') {
      throw new Error(`template for element type ${elementType} not found`)
    }
    throw e
  }

  return template
}

/**
 * @param error the error object.
 * @returns if given error object is a NodeJS error.
 */
const isNodeError = (error: Error): error is NodeJS.ErrnoException =>
  error instanceof Error
```

But I am surprised to see that this is necessary. Also it requires you to [disable tslint's](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3010) unsafe-any rule if you are using that.

Comment: Unbelievable that this is still the best solution to this problem.

Comment: I think that the guard should be:


`const isNodeError = (error: unknown): error is NodeJS.ErrnoException =>
  error instanceof Error`

Since the purpose is to refine from `unknown` to a known type.

Comment: I slightly modified it too -> `const isNodeError = (error: Error | unknown): error is NodeJS.ErrnoException => error instanceof Error`  as an exception doesn't have to be of type `Error`, and saves having to do another instance check.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use try/catch then you'll be getting an object you don't know the type of.

The code you already have tests to see if that object is an [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), and if it is then it casts it as a "normal" JS [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object.

You can use a [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to tell the type system what type the object actually is.

Something along the lines of:

```
function isError(error: any): error is ErrnoException { return error instanceof Error; }
```

---

I had a look at [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) and it seems a common way of using that function, and indeed the entire node api, is by passing it a callback which gets called either when the job is done, or there has been an error.

And looking at the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts#L4181) it shows that the error object passed to the callback is indeed the desired [ErrnoException](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts#L562).

```
export function readFile(path: PathLike | number, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void): void;
```

So using the callback will eliminate the need for the type guard, and seems to be the node way of approaching this.

[This article](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) apparently details some of the thinking behind the "callback all the things" approach.

> Node’s heavy use of callbacks dates back to a style of programming
>   older than JavaScript itself. Continuation-Passing Style (CPS) is the
>   old-school name for how Node.js uses callbacks today. In CPS, a
>   “continuation function” (read: “callback”) is passed as an argument to
>   be called once the rest of that code has been run. This allows
>   different functions to asynchronously hand control back and forth
>   across an application.
>
> Node.js relies on asynchronous code to stay fast, so having a
>   dependable callback pattern is crucial. Without one, developers would
>   be stuck maintaining different signatures and styles between each and
>   every module. The error-first pattern was introduced into Node core to
>   solve this very problem, and has since spread to become today’s
>   standard. While every use-case has different requirements and
>   responses, the error-first pattern can accommodate them all.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The typeguard seems to solve the problem, though I have to use a tslint ignore comment for the use of `any`. That pro-callback post is from 2014. Since then, much has changed. People tend to avoid callbacks to avoid deeply nested structures. `Async / await` is heavily adopted and I would not consider it a solution to go back to the old days because Typescript fails to resolve that an Error class is actually from node and not es6.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer for the Typeguard, but not for the callback suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not too ugly and works:

```js
e instanceof Error && 'code' in e && e.code === 'ENOENT'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider reading the `code` property using square brackets and then checking if its value equals `ENOENT`:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (e) {
    const code: string = e['code'];
    if (code === 'ENOENT') {
        ...
    }
    throw e
}
```

This isn't a perfect solution, but it may be good enough considering that you cannot declare types in catch clauses and that the `e instanceof ErrnoException` check doesn't work properly (as discussed in the question comments).

Comment: Thank you -- it would be surprising to me if this is the recommended approach, considering how common error handling is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the snippets below are more correct. Notice the `||` instead of `&&`.

```
const isNodeError = (error: any): error is NodeJS.ErrnoException => {
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    return 'errno' in error || 'code' in error || 'path' in error || 'syscall' in error;
  }
  return false;
};
```

```
const isNodeError = (error: any): error is NodeJS.ErrnoException => {
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    const nodeError: NodeJS.ErrnoException = error;
    return (
      (typeof nodeError.errno === 'number') ||
      (typeof nodeError.code === 'string') ||
      (typeof nodeError.path === 'string') ||
      (typeof nodeError.syscall === 'string')
    );
  }
  return false;
};
```

If you are using only the `code` property, you can simplify it even more:

```
const isNodeError = (error: any): error is NodeJS.ErrnoException => {
  return error instanceof Error && 'code' in error;
};
```

```
const isNodeError = (error: any): error is NodeJS.ErrnoException => {
  return error instanceof Error && typeof (<NodeJS.ErrnoException>error).code === 'string';
};
```